# on RAID1 (OS) and RAID5 (DATA) - Need to rebuild OS

Tags: windows, raid, hp-smart-array

I have a HP server with RAID1 (300GB2) - Array A and RAID 5 (300GB3)Array2. Unfortunately I have to rebuild the existing OS on RAID 1. I have full data on RAID 5. Can I access my RAID5 Data once I rebuild the new OS W2k12 on RAID1? Do i need to disconnect my RAID 5 disks while I'm building the OS? Any other precautions needs here?
Kindly suggest.

Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 1):

You can re-install the OS without problem without disconnect anything. The problem is if you have a disk used in Linux and Windows try to use it, or vice-versa, which don't seem your case here.

The warning I give you is simple, be sure you re-install/format the correct drive ! As both drive are 300G in size, that, can lead to an error.

Comment: Thank you Yagmoth555. I will make sure to select proper disk

Answer (score 0):

If by "rebuild OS," you mean you need to rebuild the RAID1 system array, then you don't need to reinstall the OS at all.  Simply replace the failed drive and initiate the rebuild.  The OS won't have changed at all.  The rebuild simply mirrors the first drive to the replacement drive.

If by "rebuild OS," you mean you need to reinstall the OS but that the RAID1 system array is fine and does not require rebuilding, then yes, the data on the RAID5 array will be accessible after the OS is reinstalled.

In the second case, you will, however, need to take ownership of the folders/directories on the data array on behalf of a user or users that exist on the newly installed OS because the newly installed OS will not recognize the user account references from the prior OS even if they have the same names (Windows uses lengthy user ID numbers behind the scenes).